# How to start with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, webdriver

I guess Selenium Webdriver would be the good choice but not sure, how I can use it for my day-to-day project work. Without external training, what could be the best way to go step by step and master webdriver?

Comment: Have you read the Selenium website tutorials?

Comment: first install and use Selenium IDE (firefox plugin) Write any sequence of actions. Export it as JUNIT4 (java class). Open it in any IDE (IDEA,Eclipse, etc) and get into the code. To master webDriver you will have  to get acquainted with xPath and css selectors of web elements on the page. Are you interested in details how to set up IDE properly for automation e.g. on Java?

Comment: Read selenium docs in official site
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/

Comment: @eugene.polschikov I started initially by creating brittle tests through IDE and exporting them to JUnit, but I was always interested using languages like Python or Ruby to write scripts. Hence, I thought there could be alternate approach for it.

Thanks for the tips! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As Eugene said -
Download Selenium IDE. Play along with it, recording and running test cases.

Go through the official docs.

Export test cases in the language of your choice.

Read a few blogs regarding WebDriver. Try a few code snippets.

Write your own logic for data driven or key driven test cases.

And basically keep learning.

Best of luck!

Comment: Found this link http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.in/2011/07/python-getting-started-with-selenium.html - all about how to start Selenium Webdriver with Python. Looks good enough for beginners

Answer (score 1):

There is a free udemy course which will show you how to set up and start using WebDriver with junit. You can find it here:
[Start Using Selenium WebDriver with Java](http://www.udemy.com/start-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java/)

This short course is made by Alan Richardson, author of [*Selenium Simplified*](http://www.compendiumdev.co.uk/default.php). This is an excellent book, but is directed at Selenium-RC. I am currently using the book to learn WebDriver by translating the exercises from Selenium-RC syntax.

In my experience, the best way to push yourself to learn something like automation is to have a project. For example, if you have tests you run quite often at work, consider automating them in your spare time as part of the learning process.